# Faster drawing in python pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I made a program using Python, with pygame, that loads pictures of materials and then creates blocks and each block is assigned with random material.
Block is a class and in the drawing process, it iterates through the array with stored blocks, but that is very slow. Isn't there a faster method than storing them in array and iterating through?

```
class block:
    def __init__(self, texture, x, y):
           self.texture = texture
           self.x = x
           self.y = y


material = pygame.image
material.grass = pygame.image.load("textures/grass.png")
material.water = pygame.image.load("textures/water.png")
material.sand = pygame.image.load("textures/sand.png")

materials = [material.grass, material.water, material.sand]



white = (255,255,255);(width, height) = (2048, 1008);black = (0, 0, 0);screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

b_unit = 16

b = []

count = 0
cx = 0
cy = 0
while count < (width * height) / (b_unit * b_unit):
    b.append(block(random.choice(materials), b_unit * cx, b_unit * cy))
    cx += 1
    count += 1
    if cx == width / b_unit:
        cx = 0
        cy += 1

while True:
    for block in b:
        screen.blit(block.texture, (block.x + viewx, block.y + viewy))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Always convert your images: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48574695/6220679

Comment: I don't see any real speed up tricks that can be done. You can reduce the overhead of a class with a tuple. but the speed up of that will not be noticeable. What kind of images are they (float, byte)? are there conversions happening during the blit?

Comment: Blitting the blocks separately all the time can be slow as well. If the background doesn't change during the game, it's probably better to blit the background `block`s onto a big surface when the program starts and then just blit this background surface once each frame.

Comment: @J. Bakker they are 16x16 png images

Comment: @skrx ok, so how do i do it?

Comment: @skrx converting images works! thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've already mentioned in the comments that you should (almost) always [convert your images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48574695/6220679) to improve the performance.

It can also help to blit separate images/pygame.Surfaces onto a big background surface and then just blit this background once per frame. I use two nested for loops here to get the coordinates and randomly blit one of two images.

I get around 120 fps if I use separate sprites (5184) here and ~430 fps with this single background image.

Of course I'm just blitting here and in a real game you'd probably have to store the rects of the tiles in a list or use pygame sprites and sprite groups, for example to implement collision detection or other map related logic, so the frame rate would be lower.

```
import itertools

import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


BLUE_IMAGE = pg.Surface((20, 20))
BLUE_IMAGE.fill(pg.Color('lightskyblue2'))
GRAY_IMAGE = pg.Surface((20, 20))
GRAY_IMAGE.fill(pg.Color('slategray4'))


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()

    images = itertools.cycle((BLUE_IMAGE, GRAY_IMAGE))
    background = pg.Surface(screen.get_size())
    # Use two nested for loops to get the coordinates.
    for y in range(screen.get_height()//20):
        for x in range(screen.get_width()//20):
            # This alternates between the blue and gray image.
            image = next(images)
            # Blit one image after the other at their respective coords.
            background.blit(image, (x*20, y*20))
        next(images)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        # Now you can just blit the background image once
        # instead of blitting thousands of separate images.
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        pg.display.set_caption(str(clock.get_fps()))
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(1000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

---

Side notes: Don't add your images to the `pygame.image` module (that makes no sense at all).

```
material = pygame.image
material.grass = pygame.image.load("textures/grass.png")
```

Writing several statements in the same row separated with semicolons is really ugly and makes code less readable.

```
white = (255,255,255);(width, height) = (2048, 1008)
```